# Tkinter canvas drawing image

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, raspberry-pi, python-3.7, tkinter-canvas

I have several labels on the interface and I want an image, "arkaplan.pbm" to be shown in the background. I'm using this format because I made it work with label's image displaying method so I'm assuming canvas can also support pbm file.

So far I either managed to show labels or the image, never together. I was using a label to draw the image. So I switched to canvas method but now I don't see any image at all.

I'm using Python 3.7 and developing this on Raspberry Pi's 7inch screen. What am I doing wrong?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import time
from tkinter import * 
import tkinter.font 
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

country = "Turkey"
notification_duration = 10
refresh_time = 10 #minutes
data_check= []
worldmetersLink = "https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/"

win = tkinter.Tk() 
arkaplan_PIL = Image.open("/home/pi/Desktop/arkaplan.pbm")
arkaplan_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(arkaplan_PIL)

def data_cleanup(array):
    L = []
    for i in array:
        i = i.replace("+","")
        i = i.replace("-","")
        i = i.replace(",",".")
        if i == "":
            i = "0"
        L.append(i.strip())
    return L

win.geometry('800x480') 
win.attributes('-fullscreen', True) 


while True:
    try:
        html_page = requests.get(worldmetersLink)
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        print (e)
        continue
    bs = BeautifulSoup(html_page.content, 'html.parser')

    search = bs.select("div tbody tr td")
    start = -1
    for i in range(len(search)):
        if search[i].get_text().find(country) !=-1:
            start = i
            break
    data = []
    for i in range(1,8):
        try:
            data = data + [search[start+i].get_text()]
        except:
            data = data + ["0"]

    data= data_cleanup(data)



    if data_check != data:
        data_check = data
        toplam_vaka=data[0]
        toplam_vefat = data[2]
        toplam_taburcu = data[4]

        etiket1 = Label(win, text=(toplam_vaka),bg="white",fg="black",font = "Helvetica 26 bold italic")
        etiket1.place(x=500, y=200)

        etiket2 = Label(win, text=(toplam_vefat),bg="white",fg="black",font = "Helvetica 20 bold italic")
        etiket2.place(x=450, y=300) 

        etiket3 = Label(win, text = (toplam_taburcu),bg="white",fg="black",font = "Helvetica 20 bold italic")
        etiket3.place(x=600, y=300) 

        canv = Canvas(win, width=800, height=480, background="white")
        canv.create_image(800, 480, image = arkaplan_image)

        win.mainloop()
    else:
        time.sleep(refresh_time*60)
        continue
```

Comment: You did not call any layout function (ie `pack()`, `place()`) on the `canv`.

Comment: Additionally, you probably want to place your `Label`s in the `Canvas` and not the window.